# MySQL. Capture Cis program makes incorrect query: SELECT DISTINCT "PartType" FROM "Capacitor" ORDER BY "PartType"

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mariadb, errors

I am having problems to get one database running. I have a MySQL in my server, the server is running "5.5.48-MariaDB - MariaDB Server" with "UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)"

I have a MySQL ODBC 64 bits 3.51 Driver to be able to connect to this database. The ODBC is configure to use utf8 character set.

If I use for example MySQL workbench to connect to this database for example:

```
SELECT * FROM leomaker_prueba_01.Capacitor;
```

All is perfect, I get the data. Also work with:

```
SELECT DISTINCT PartType FROM Capacitor ORDER BY PartType
```

I think that this is the correct form to make query of this kind.

The problem start with my program: "OrCAD Capture Cis". This program make a connection to a Database to fetch data and use it in the program.

In the console of the program I get this error:

> ODBC Error Description: State:S0001,Native:1050,Origin:[MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver][mysqld-5.5.48-MariaDB] SELECT DISTINCT "PartType" FROM "Capacitor" ORDER BY "PartType" ERROR(ORCIS-6245): Database Operation
>   Failed  Please Check Session For More Details ERROR(ORCIS-6250): ODBC
>   Error Code: -1 Description: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for
>   the right syntax to use near '"Capacitor" ORDER BY "PartType"' at line
>   1

As we see the query that it makes is

```
SELECT DISTINCT "PartType" FROM "Capacitor" ORDER BY "PartType"
```

Which is incorrect. I also try it in MySQL Workbench and i get the same kind of errors. I am sure that is problems of the " symbols.

The default database connect to a local SQL server. (but i can't see the querys)

Which could be the problem? I try to use MariaDB ODBC and i get the same error. Also if I try to change of character set.

It could be any form to change the querys to the database?

Thanks

Comment: The query is correct, in ANSI mode. In ANSI mode, table and column names can be quoted with with double quotes `"`. In the default (non ANSI mode), table and column names can be quoted with backquotes `\`` and double quoted strings are taken as string literals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved, the problems was the ODBC connector. I have to use the ODBC MySQL 5.1 instead of 3.5, due to my MySQL server uses 5.5.

This solve the problem with the "